# Why am I getting Error 404 in slides api? I just copy pasted the code from the google website, and added my presentation ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api

```
  const request = {
    name: copyTitle,
  };
  try {
    gapi.client.drive.files.copy({
      fileId: presentationId,
      resource: request,
    }).then((driveResponse) => {
      const presentationCopyId = driveResponse.result.id;
      if (callback) callback(presentationCopyId);
      console.log('create copy_presentation with id', presentationCopyId);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
    return;
  }
}
```

Whenever I deploy this in Google Apps script, I get Error 404 (404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /v1/scripts/AKfycbzr3AFNL9qvlzGV98zsJ3AsYxWv0Rx6pQK96A2sp0uPT0N1CzEHk4pF2FSFN5Jr7ZDO9w:run was not found on this server. That’s all we know) I'm running it as an executable API. It's meant to duplicate the presentation, and I tried it several times and got the same error.  Sorry if this is a dumb question lol, I'm very new to coding

Comment: obviously your deployment urls has changed

Comment: I'm doing the thing where I edit an existing deployment to new version, so idk

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: I thought that when I saw your script, no error occurs. When the authorization and permissions are correct, when I tested your script, I confirmed that no error occurs and a Google Slides could be copied. I apologize that I cannot replicate your issue. In order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.